# Convert List to Json String then Convert this String back to List in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, converters, typeconverter

I want to convert a list `List<Word> myList`to `String` and put it into sharedPreference and later I also want to convert that string (from sharedPreference) back to `List<Word>`.

Here is my model class `Word`

```
class Word {
  int id;
  String word;
  String meaning;
  String fillInTheGapSentence;

  Word.empty();

  Word(int id, String word, String meaning, String fillInTheGapSentence){
    this.id = id;
    this.word = word;
    this.meaning = meaning;
    this.fillInTheGapSentence = fillInTheGapSentence;
  }
}
```

I can convert the `List<Word> myList` to String like this

```
var myListString = myList.toString();
```

But couldn't make `List<Word> myListFromString` from `myListString`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `myList.toString()` is not in JSON format, unless you override `toString()` method. What you have to do is manually transform the object into a Dictionary then encoded it to JSON string. In reverse, you need to convert the string into a dictionary, then transform it into an object. Something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Word {
  int id;
  String word;
  String meaning;
  String fillInTheGapSentence;

  Word.empty();

  Word(int id, String word, String meaning, String fillInTheGapSentence) {
    this.id = id;
    this.word = word;
    this.meaning = meaning;
    this.fillInTheGapSentence = fillInTheGapSentence;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': this.id,
      'word': this.word,
      'meaning': this.meaning,
      'fillInTheGapSentence': this.fillInTheGapSentence,
    };
  }

  factory Word.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return new Word(
      map['id'] as int,
      map['word'] as String,
      map['meaning'] as String,
      map['fillInTheGapSentence'] as String,
    );
  }
}

String convertToJson(List<Word> words) {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonData =
      words.map((word) => word.toMap()).toList();
  return jsonEncode(jsonData);
}

List<Word> fromJSon(String json) {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonData = jsonDecode(json);
  return jsonData.map((map) => Word.fromMap(map)).toList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got my code to work with a few tweaks in yours. (Specifically the `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` part in `fromJson`)

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of **serialization** and there is a lot of them. One of the most popular one is JSON serialization.

Flutter has pretty good documentation how to do that:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

You want to:

1. Transform your object into Map
2. Encode your Map into JSON (which is a String)
3. Save it
4. Retrieve it as String
5. Decode your JSON as Map
6. Transform your Map into object